# How to place an UserControl in foreground?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I need to display a UserControl over the screen, o top of everything.

With the following code UserControl show content under ContentGrid.

How do I place UserControl in foreground?

---

Main.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <local:AdvertisementsFullScreen>
    </local:AdvertisementsFullScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ZIndex**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx

```
<Grid>
<Grid Panel.ZIndex="1">
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="50" Height="50" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="50" Height="50" Panel.ZIndex="0" />
</Grid>
<Grid Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="50" Height="50" Panel.ZIndex="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="50" Height="50" Panel.ZIndex="0" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<UserControl Panel.ZIndex="100" />
```

On my UserControl, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve what you're after. One way would be to set the [`Panel.ZIndex` attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it:

```
<local:AdvertisementsFullScreen Panel.ZIndex="10" />
```

Another is just to declare it underneath other controls on the XAML page:

```
<local:AdvertisementsFullScreen /> 
<local:AdvertisementsFullScreen /> <!-- This one is on top -->
```

A third, perhaps more suitable method is to use the [`Adorner` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The [Adorner Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a visual layer above the normal layer where UI elements are displayed. While it is not normally used to display whole `UserControl`s, it *is* possible. Please see the answer to the [WPF adorner with controls inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998691/wpf-adorner-with-controls-inside) question here on Stack Overflow for further information on this.

Comment: Ahhh... I took too long, eh? meh.