# WPF Adorner Newbee

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Using VB.Net & WPF

I'm Using Code Available at [Overlaying Controls in WPF with Adorners](http://bignickolson.com/2009/10/15/overlaying-controls-in-wpf-with-adorners/) (Converted to VB.Net)

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Name="G1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text=" This is Parent Control " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Show Child Control " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
Class MainWindow 

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim U1 As New UserControl1
    Using OverlayAdorner(Of UserControl).Overlay(G1, U1)

    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background=" #44000000">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text=" This is Child Control " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Name="T1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Close Child Control " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Code Behind

```
Public Class UserControl1

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

End Sub

Public Property UserInput As String
    Get
        Return T1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        T1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Now when user clicks on button in mainwindow, usercontrol1 should open as adorner and allow user to enter some text in textbox and when user clicks button in usercontrol1 it should close and return text to mainwindow where it would be displayed as message box.

Please Help me to achive the same as i'm newbie in wpf

Comment: what is the issue/question? I do not see any `?` in the whole description.

Comment: @pushpraj he told me about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25133412/468718) He has this error message `Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual. at Private Sub New(elementToAdorn As UIElement, adorningElement As UIElement)` (y)

Comment: Using above code usercontrol1 is not shown and not even any err message is shown.

Comment: @Harash, The Issue or err was when I used your way of initializing UserControl in XAML but in above code I'm initializing UserControl in VB.Net Code and Not XAML

Comment: To me it seems like you are complicating it, in general adorners are used to display overlay content like drag preview, resize handles, error messages etc. you may perhaps use `Popup` for the same purpose.

Comment: What I want to do is When a textbox gets focus a new window should open and user can search names from grid and then user selection is returned to caller and is processed accourdingly

Comment: Since user response in Popup window is to be processed, the main form should be disabled or should not get focus till popup window is open

Comment: Popup is your preferred choice here. if you want to disable other operations while the child is open then perhaps a model window or a overlay control can solve your issue.

Comment: Modal Window works fine in Windows Form Application, I'm preparing or using wpf for Web Application

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to write a pure xaml based solution, you may adjust as per your needs

in this sample there are 2 textboxes 1st is regular while other popups a list when focused and allow you to select an item from it

sample code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 MinWidth="200">
        <TextBox Text="regular textbox" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=list,TargetNullValue=select an item}">
            <TextBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="true"
                                                         KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBox.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border Background="#77000000"
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=button,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="300"
              Height="150">
            <ListBox x:Name="list">
                <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
                <sys:String>item 3</sys:String>
                <sys:String>item 4</sys:String>
                <ListBox.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="button"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False"
                                                             KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ListBox.Triggers>
            </ListBox>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="False"
                          x:Name="button"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Content="X"
                          ToolTip="Close" />
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Opacity=".5" />
            </Grid.Effect>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

content of the grid inside the border is where you'll place your user control

just copy this code to a new project's main window and run it. give it a try and see if this is close to your needs, we can work out to fit it according to your needs.